# Access Android via batch file

Tags: android, windows, batch-file

I want a batch file to copy a series of files from my PC to my android.

I tried copying the path from the windows Explorer screen thus:

```
copy "C:\Users\user1\Documents\copy files\route*.pdf" "\Computer\name\Tablet\Documents\."
```

but it keeps giving me:

```
 The system cannot find the path specified
```

How do I need to designate the tablet?

The tablet is connected via USB

Answer (score 0):

you can copy using adb

```
adb push C:/Users/user1/Documents/copy files/route.pdf /Path/in/your/tab
```

Comment: As a developer, sure, but ADB is not intended for end user solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have a warm fuzzy going with ADB.  I'd probably push the wrong button & brick my PC, tablet, or both.  Thanks, but maybe I should just stick with drag & drop from explorer for now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use adb push to copy files

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#copyfiles

Answer (score 0):

copy "C:\Users\user1\Documents\copy files\route*.pdf" "\Computer\name\Tablet\Documents."

Could be a typo?

The protocol to copy to a folder shared on another computer is:

"\computername\sharename\folder" (and you can have \folder2\folder3 , etc)

the above should be two backslashes but not showing it when I post?

\ \ computername

If you need rights, you can include username and password

/user:username password

But if you are connecting via USB it probably isn't a network share but rather a local share as Windows usually assigns a drive letter to the device.  Is that not the case?

Comment: It's adding it on the same level as my drives, but not *as* a drive, and neither a share.  When I plug in my Garmin, or a flash drive, yes, it assigns a drive letter, but not my tablet.

Comment: I've heard that accessing a tablet or other mobile device with it's own operating system directly from the Windows command line is not possible. You can write or use a program written in C, Java,  or certain other languages to access it indirectly but can't access it like another drive and copy,  move,  rename files on it.  Allegedly Microsoft claims this is intentionally not allowed as a security measure. I have been unable to  find where they say this on their site though.